# How to parse json data using in java

Tags: java, json

I am getting this data from server how to parse this data in java .

LabelField jsonResult = new LabelField(connectJson.response);

```
"[{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"}]"
```

I am getting response in jsonResult  variable

Comment: What is `LabelField`  ? Have you thought about using a json lib like [GSon](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to do the same. There is also Google's GSON which will help you do the same. See this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse plugin than may JSON library included in you SDK.
Use below code to parse your JSON string got from the server.

```
String test = "[{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"}]";    

JSONArray array = new JSONArray(test);
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) array.get(0);
```

Your String look like you got JSON Array from the server.
First convert your Json string to JSON Array by

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(Your JSON String);
```

Each element in array represent JSON Object.You can read JSON Object by

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) array.get(Index);
```

You can read parameter from Object to any String variable by :

```
String valueStr = obj.getString("screen_refresh_interval");
```

May this help you.

Comment: xjson.me.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of "[{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"}]"

Comment: @user944513  which library are you Using ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JSONParser Object in this [Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Design a class (viz *CustomClass*) first with `screen_refresh_interval` and `station_list_last_update` as properties. And Make a collection class for *CustomClass*

I'm using Gson as deserializer. Other libraries are also available.

```
public class Container {
    private CustomClass[] classes;

    public CustomClass[] getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

    public void setClasses(CustomClass[] classes) {
        this.classes = classes;
    }
}

public class CustomClass {
    private String screen_refresh_interval;
    private String station_list_last_update;
    public String getScreen_refresh_interval() {
        return screen_refresh_interval;
    }
    public void setScreen_refresh_interval(String screen_refresh_interval) {
        this.screen_refresh_interval = screen_refresh_interval;
    }
    public String getStation_list_last_update() {
        return station_list_last_update;
    }
    public void setStation_list_last_update(String station_list_last_update) {
        this.station_list_last_update = station_list_last_update;
    }
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
Container customClassCollection = gson.fromJson(jsonResult, Container.class);
```